# php get html after user is logged with curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to get get the contents from a webpage but the user sees different information depending if he is logged or not. I want to send header information with curl to simulate that the use is logged in.
I inspected the network and these are the response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 13 Jun 2017 08:08:52 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Location:http://dims-92.com/ClientNewsPage
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.30
```

And there is this request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SubmitControlId"

Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ParameterInfo"

undefined
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput"


------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput"

user
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_PasswordInput"

password
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb--
```

I have tried this:

```
$url = "http://dims-92.com/ClientDisplayProductFolder?param=4553686f703a434e493d3935343b434e494c3d3b5649443d3b543d42473b";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb',
    'Content-Length: 671',
    '------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SubmitControlId"

Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ParameterInfo"

undefined
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput"


------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput"

user
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_PasswordInput"

password
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb--'
));
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
```

but the page I see just says: **Bad Request**

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Request header field is missing ':' separator.
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb

Answer (score 1):

You can't post headers like this, they have to be in an array like so :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'Content-Length: 671',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data',
    ....
));
```

The problem is that you post the entire payload (things like `boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb'`), which is invalid.

Comment: I now have this

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb',
    'Content-Length: 671',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SubmitControlId"',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ParameterInfo"',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput"',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput"',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_PasswordInput"',
));`
but how I set the username and pass

Comment: I think you did not read what I said. You have to remove all the `boundary------- ...` parts and all the `name="FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput"` parts from the headers array.

Comment: I removed it
now I have this : `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;` and `'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput"'` but how do I set the value for the username and password on those fields ?

Comment: Again, you need to remove all the `name="..."` parts...
For username and password you'll have to pass them in 2 separate instructions as POST parameters. But I don't see how that would help here. To simulate that the user is logged in you'll have to do it in 2 passes. First send the POST request to get a cookie, then send a GET request with the cookie in the header to gather the information you need as a logged in user.

Comment: POST request to which page?
The one with the login form or the one which I want to take the information from? And what must the POST request contain ?

Comment: what you're saying in the top post is technically wrong. you CAN technically set the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header manually, then give the form-data encoded data in CURLOPT_INFILE ... but 99.9999% of the time, you would just want to set the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, and let curl form-data-encode it for you.

Comment: another thing, when using `multipart/form-data` encoding, or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, don't set the `Content-Type` or `Content-Length` or `Content-Disposition` headers manually. that is error-prone and unnecessary. libcurl will set them for you automatically, if you don't, which is easier and safer.

Answer (score 1):

your code is confusing the requests' HTTP HEADERS and the HTTP BODY

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Length: 671
```

these are parts of the HTTP REQUEST HEADERS, and indeed goes into the CURLOPT_HTTP**HEADER**.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SubmitControlId"

Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart
------WebKitFormBoundaryaSWkHLJeD9EymCJb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ParameterInfo"

undefined
```

this is part of the HTTP REQUEST BODY, the body does not go in CURLOPT_HTTP**HEADER**.

now, contrary to what Julien Lachal says in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517070/1067003 , you can actually encode the entire request body yourself (using `CURLOPT_POST` or `CURLOPT_INFILE`), but when using `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, its easier, safer, and less error prone, to let curl encode it for you. (the usual reason for encoding it yourself, is when POSTing to a JSON API requiring `content-type: application/json`, curl does not support encoding to JSON automatically.)

to tell curl to do it for you, simply use `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, like this:

```
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array (
                'SubmitControlId' => 'Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart',
                'ParameterInfo' => 'undefined',
                'FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput' => '',
                'FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput' => 'user',
                'FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_PasswordInput' => 'password' 
        ) 
) );
```

now libcurl will automatically `multipart/form-data`-encode it, and set the correct `content-type`, and set the correct `content-length` header, and the actual HTTP request will look like:

Http Request Headers:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 686
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------b6890d3827808ee1
```

Http Request Body:

```
--------------------------b6890d3827808ee1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SubmitControlId"

Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart
--------------------------b6890d3827808ee1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ParameterInfo"

undefined
--------------------------b6890d3827808ee1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput"


--------------------------b6890d3827808ee1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput"

user
--------------------------b6890d3827808ee1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_PasswordInput"

password
--------------------------b6890d3827808ee1--
```

however, note that many websites doesn't support `multipart/form-data` and/or prefer `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding. to use that, use http_build_query on the data to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, like this:

```
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'SubmitControlId' => 'Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart',
                'ParameterInfo' => 'undefined',
                'FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput' => '',
                'FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput' => 'user',
                'FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_PasswordInput' => 'password' 
        ) ),
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' 
) );
```

now the actual HTTP request looks like this:

HTTP request headers:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 204
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

HTTP request body:

```
SubmitControlId=Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart&ParameterInfo=undefined&FC_CEShop_SearchControl_SearchInput=&FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_UsernameInput=user&FC_CAuthenticate_LogIn_PasswordInput=password
```

Comment: @hanshernik 
Thanks for the detailed answer. I've tried it but it still not working. It just returns the page but witht the wrong info (it's not the info it shows when the user is logged in).

Comment: @TheAngelM97 well, to login there, you require a cookie session (which you don't have any code to aquire), and an `ParameterInfo` token which probably changes regularly. you provide no code to get a cookie session, and you try to hardcode an old ParameterInfo token that has long since expired. that definitely aint going to work. here's my attempt, i think this will work, with a real username/password: http://paste.debian.net/971420/ .the hhb_curl class i use, takes care of handling cookies and sessions automatically. you can use $hc->getResponseCookies() to see the cookies of the last response

Comment: @TheAngelM97 Correction! i forgot, SubmitControlId is also set by javascript dynamically, you need to add `$inputs['SubmitControlId']='Auto_CAuthenticate_LogIn_LogIn_Standart';` for it to work